# Keyboard shortcut for double clicking (highlighting a word) in Windows?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

Does anyone know of a tool or keyboard shortcut for double clicking and highlighting a word in Windows? I'm getting clicker's finger with a particular task and looking for keyboard alternatives for word highlighting

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dunno if there's a Windows-wide one (I think it probably depends on the app) but there is always the cumbersome

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>

Comment: That's also what I would go for. You could make a macro out of that and assign that to a single keystroke. I also searched for commands you can apply to keystrokes and found nothing along the lines of "select whole word". So apparently it's not there out of the box.

Comment: Looks like this is the closest I'll get and have to stick to the double clicking

Answer (score 1):

Some programs have also their own application specific shortcuts. My answer is specifically for MS Word if someone is interested in that.

MS Word has F8, which enters the user into a selection mode as the cursors current location as starting point. Then you can use your arrow keys or other possible keys to extend the selection. If you press F8 again, it will automatically select the current word. After pressing F8 again, it will now select the current sentence. F8 again and its the current paragraph. F8 again and its all header content. F8 again and it's whole document. When you press ESC it will quit the selection mode.

> <kbd>F8</kbd> = Enter selection mode at cursors current location
>   <kbd>F8</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd> = Select current word
>   <kbd>F8</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd> = Select current sentence
>   <kbd>F8</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd> =  Select current paragraph
>   <kbd>F8</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd> = Select current document header content
>   <kbd>F8</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd> = Select current document content
>   <kbd>ESC</kbd> = Quit selection mode