# Double click with the keyboard instead of the mouse?

Tags: keyboard, mouse

I tried 
http://www.wikihow.com/Use-a-Keyboard-to-Click-Instead-of-a-Mouse

and it doesn't seem to work

pressing + simulates a right click

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set mouse or keyboard button to simulate left click and hold or rapid left click repeating in Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/365866/set-mouse-or-keyboard-button-to-simulate-left-click-and-hold-or-rapid-left-click), [keyboard shortcut for mouse right click](http://superuser.com/questions/195167/keyboard-shortcut-for-mouse-right-click), [Keyboard shortcut for double clicking (highlighting a word) in Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/29279/keyboard-shortcut-for-double-clicking-highlighting-a-word-in-windows) etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases, pressing enter while the item you'd like to click on is selected will result in the same action as a double click. http://www.bilbo.com/shortcut.html

Comment: i want to like your comment, i feel really dumb, never tried that before.  neuropathy must be clogging up my brain

Comment: no. enter action is not a double-click action. First is similar to validate thing and other is for specific action on the item. Question is very interesting for users find out how to discard your mouse but this response bring nothing about this.